# Types of property 'value' are incompatible / ts(2322)

Tags: typescript

In short I have a type `FieldHeader`

```ts
interface Item {
  id: string;
}

interface BaseFieldHeader<
  item extends Item,
  value extends boolean | number | string
> {
  get: (item: item) => value;
}

type FieldHeader<item extends Item> =
  | (BaseFieldHeader<item, boolean> & {
    type: 'boolean';
  })
  | (BaseFieldHeader<item, number> & {
    type: 'number';
  })
  | (BaseFieldHeader<item, string> & {
    type: 'string';
  });
```

that is used to create `Field`s by evaluating `get` with an `Item`:

```ts
interface BaseField<value extends boolean | number | string> {
  key: string;
  value: value;
}

type Field =
  | (BaseField<boolean> & {
    type: 'boolean';
  })
  | (BaseField<number> & {
    type: 'number';
  })
  | (BaseField<string> & {
    type: 'string';
  });
```

`type` will always match the return type of `get` / the type of `value` resp.

Thus, setting

```ts
type TableHeader<item extends Item> = Record<
  string,
  FieldHeader<item>
>;
```

and—given an `Item` `User`—creating fields from a `TableHeader` like so

```ts
interface User extends Item {
  age: number;
}

const tableHeader: TableHeader<User> = {
  age: {
    get: (user) => user.age,
    type: "number"
  }
}

const user: User = {
  id: "frank",
  age: 34
}

const tableRow: Field[] = Object.entries(tableHeader).map(
  ([key, field]) =>
  ({
    key,
    value: field.get(user),
    type: field.type,
  }
  )
)
```

why do I get the error

```
Type '{ key: string; value: string | number | boolean; type: "string" | "number" | "boolean"; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Field[]'.
  Type '{ key: string; value: string | number | boolean; type: "string" | "number" | "boolean"; }' is not assignable to type 'Field'.
    Type '{ key: string; value: string | number | boolean; type: "string" | "number" | "boolean"; }' is not assignable to type 'BaseField<string> & { type: "string"; }'.
      Type '{ key: string; value: string | number | boolean; type: "string" | "number" | "boolean"; }' is not assignable to type 'BaseField<string>'.
        Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
          Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
            Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

? [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnLAAmAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgL666iSyIoBCc5EAYsAgAbIgAkIcItAA8%20QpmQQAHpBBFyaTABp5ANzjCArihVqNyAEYB7a8MkhkAH2QgjGS9GcUqtXAD4ceRoIMDIACmBMMiiIDABKZABeQINjCAZmXDAATwAHFEERcUlpKBlYrDMIdU10OMCk%20Rdwnj4i0QkpWUrtK1t7OBBAgDIgggJcgrIAchs7BxmGAkZ45uRW3gEhTtKenVd3TyhR8YmpiFm3D2gl%20VX1zfadku7y3p9qEBpTvAnkC6zShfGh3FbxBiscDQeBIZBtbbFGRpExKVQ1CzzQaOFzXY7eYG0QJ-ZAAawgOTIhO%20y2QKMudMMJkyLAuyA6RGSjwRHJkWIcv3kk3yDLmA0WtIeBBaPJeMjx0EF-0ByBmCqgYOQUu8T0Rohk1J%20yDGJOF01Vhs1q0hbIAKnBLPYumUKopqrUtA1ksgAEoQBDWKBEOQEQ26Agc537BoBSFsGGcZAAVT4UDR5jqihJcBCZHVLNwAZAlABDqdeygZHtjogUfKKcV3uzubOBBCYQ2RlTiRSyC70AAdDmIOHziKyAAidUT%205MFhFkv9yvJ1NN%20TEScwKBDUkT0fDsgAZgALHPC9Zi2BSzWfdYAO5kDkAbQAut6APKWABW-rAA5qvgQOQ4RgGWtYVvEA4YHAeThPI4RPuSOR9DALwvj2-jwaaZIUqOBD0mQqHFAO7bhEu8R4QC47IERogDhco7MAQazxEAA)

Comment: I think the issue is that you are using `field.get` and `field.type` kinda independent, and therefore `type` is being `"string" | "number" | "boolean"` and `get` returns `string | number | boolean`. Not the best solution, but [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpxkBm) works without error. I will think if there is a better approach to do this

Comment: ① Lowercase type parameter names like `item` are unconventional and therefore distracting and potentially confusing; please consider [edit]ing to single uppercase character names like `I` instead.

Comment: ②​ The problem you're having is with TS's inability to deal directly with what I call "correlated unions" as described in [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); the recommended approach is to refactor to generics as described in [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). For your example the fix looks like [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wO5d6m). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Thanks, `switch` seems to a reasonable solution and the only one that works so far

Comment: @jcalz I like your approach better, but I do not like the need of using `mapTableHeaderToFieldArray` and also exposing `K` seems wrong.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, this is the way TS works, as described in the two github issues I linked.  Your question is "why do I get the error", and the answer is in there, and the TS recommended refactoring is as described. I can't imagine a more authoritative and sourced answer.  Do you want me to write that up?  Or do you want to [edit] your question to ask about workarounds specifically and then I can disengage since you apparently you prefer `switch` to the TS-recommended refactoring.  Either way, let me know.

Comment: I agree with @jcalz; however, if you prefer the switch  version I can write up an answer

Comment: Ok you are right. Thanks to both of you @jcalz & wonderflame. If you jcalz could write up your answer as it is this would help me alot.

Comment: @wonderflame see above ^

Comment: @jcalz If I'm using your union type, when working on a `TableHeader` types are resolved to `never` that is the intersection of `boolean`, `number` and `string`. How can I resolve this? Maybe you could have a look, it's closely related to this question and your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76350339/argument-of-type-string-number-boolean-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-t

Comment: I will write up an answer here when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem TypeScript is having with your code is that it cannot analyze the type of single value `{ key, value: field.get(user), type: field.type }` multiple times.  It does so all at once, and therefore `value` is of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `string | number | boolean` and `type` is of the union type `"string" | "number" | "boolean"`, and any *correlation* between them has been lost.  TypeScript therefore cannot directly support "correlated union types", as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

If the compiler could analyze that value once for each possible union member of the type of `field`, then it would see that each member works separately and thus works overall.  But if the compiler did this whenever it encountered a value of a union type, [it would be catastrophically damaging to performance](https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1544414378383925250).  So that's not possible.  You could manually lead the compiler through analysis by using a `switch` statement or series of `if`/`else` clauses, but then you'd be writing the same value multiple times.

The *easiest* approach is just to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) because you're smarter than the compiler:

```
const tableRow: Field[] = Object.entries(tableHeader).map(
  ([key, field]) => ({
    key,
    value: field.get(user),
    type: field.type,
  } as Field)
);
```

but then it's your job to make sure you did it right, not the compiler's.  You've taken over type safety verification from the compiler.

---

There is a recommended approach to dealing with correlated unions in a way that the compiler can follow.  It's described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and involves refactoring to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) instead of unions. Generics are the only really supported way of getting the compiler to analyze "multiple cases at once".

In particular you want to represent the operations in terms of some basic key-value interface and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that interface, as well as generic [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) such types.

For your code example it might look like this. The basic key-value interface is:

```
interface TypeMap {
  boolean: boolean;
  number: number;
  string: string;
}
```

which represents the relationship between the `type` property and the corresponding data type.  Then we can rewrite your `FieldHeader` and `TableFieldHeader` types in terms of it as follows:

```
type FieldHeader<I extends Item, K extends keyof TypeMap = keyof TypeMap> =
  { [P in K]: {
    type: P,
    get: (item: I) => TypeMap[P]
  } }[K]

type Field<K extends keyof TypeMap = keyof TypeMap> =
  { [P in K]: {
    type: P,
    key: string;
    value: TypeMap[P]
  } }[K]
```

These are both *distributive object types* that evaluate to unions by immediately indexing into mapped types. They are also written to be generic so that, say, `Field<"string">` is just the `string`-related member of the union.  Similarly `TableHeader` is expanded to be generic that way:

```
type TableHeader<I extends Item, K extends keyof TypeMap = keyof TypeMap> =
  Record<string, FieldHeader<I, K>>;
```

And now we can write the code to convert an item/table-header pair into an array of fields.  This needs to be generic in `K extends keyof TypeMap` in order for the compiler to understand that this works, so we have to make a generic function.  This *could* be an anonymous function expression but it's probably clearer to give it a name:

```
function mapTableHeaderToFieldArray<I extends Item, K extends keyof TypeMap>(
  item: I, tableHeader: TableHeader<I, K>): Field<K>[] {
  return Object.entries(tableHeader).map(([key, field]) => ({
    key,
    type: field.type,
    value: field.get(item)
  }))
}
```

That compiles without error.  And now we can finally use it:

```
const user: User = {
  id: "frank",
  age: 34
}

const tableRow: Field[] =
  mapTableHeaderToFieldArray(user, tableHeader);
```

Hooray, it works!

---

In the above refactoring everything now compiles without error, and it is as close as we can get to having the compiler verify type safety for us.  But is it worth it?  That depends strongly on your use cases.  If you really want the compiler to complain if you make a mistake and you don't want to write out a bunch of manual cases, then it might be worth it.  But if you value idiomatic code and developer productivity more than you value compiler-verified type safety, then you should probably just use a type assertion and move on; it's not wrong to do so, as long as you're aware of the options and have assessed their relative applicability to your needs.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/PQKgUAxg9gdgzgFwAQIIYCMA2BTASlAdwC4kAxAS20wBMBtAXSQF4kB5dAK2wgQDpsYCAE6U4ACjRZsACWypq2IQEpeAW1QAHMWCRIxtANbYAngBokAM0o16S5gD49Abx26kRs690A3VJgCu2CRWVNS8AObYCGL+cIpKpl4oxhpBltZhCCnYiboAvkiocGQZSmBKANxgIMBgYOSCihaoENhIAJII2KpILrrk1CSIIjDhVXl1DV1Cza1IACrZALKava7oUFA4qDAkG1tyMFW6MP6q6Iokp+eKx0jDDeFDwo-jdVmpJaGy8ooAPO0kNgAB5dGDUYqdbrmADSQNBAgh7hMUAsC2WqxYHlR6NSKw0jiYricSFoAAUkA0kDD6CQ+m4Pmkybk3JEECQxOQuqoSO07ExHIs8ZpyfRXAU8rQae9sl8aH84SCwUjsWihdh8cxkcYcer8YTiaSKVSaXSkoySMykh5niMxklfAE0nqRWSxfkkJLpWBGQsMDgfgohAD4crIdzYaHEcVVbiNZjtbqMQTmK5cNwoEJqH8HqNzBRvnIgwDYfZ7FV6o0Zi02gBVOJCKPg8PdNa6VCRK5nC5CN6QWCIFD+mRFy5+qSB-71xSEtuFTtz3RsjmxeIOJCroS8Ds5c3ZEgAImuPYP4rAEzAFn8MB45FgSHUGnmw8nQnmUALNAAgkIhKhjCGSrRh0EbUk2Koomqyb2No-Tcry5iSAGo5CCQz4TihJbUvYSgkJ+2YwvYDBzkIUT+EIMBsJw3B8AILzYOISEjr8yhqJoYj6B45ghDY-KOGI9K6Fxe6pMEGS8IyLI+H4gRiaEERRJy3JlPkShlBe0DwMgm4kNOjYsPSAyHhYf4wAYB4sjuJAAMwACznnUmmDkx+DEHKdCMESuiPuhyEse++E-n+xgxA2iEvihlR1HUQA)

Comment: And again, thank you for this great and instructive answer