# Argument of type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. ts2345

Tags: typescript, union-types

I'm using the following union type

```ts
interface TypeMap {
  boolean: boolean;
  number: number;
  string: string;
}

interface Item {
  id: string;
}

type FieldHeader<I extends Item> = {
  [Type in keyof TypeMap]: {
    compare: (a: TypeMap[Type], b: TypeMap[Type]) => number;
    filter: (value: TypeMap[Type], input: TypeMap[Type]) => boolean;
    get: (item: I) => TypeMap[Type] | null | undefined;
    type: Type;
  };
}[keyof TypeMap];
```

Setting

```ts
type TableHeader<I extends Item> = Record<
  string,
  FieldHeader<I>
>;

type Filter<I extends Item, T extends TableHeader<I>> = {
  [Field in keyof T]: TypeMap[T[Field]['type']];      // this isn't working
}
```

firstly, the type of properties of `Filter` is not deduced correctly. Given an `Item` and `TableHeader` definition I could define a `Filter` with any property key and any value without getting any errors, see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECydPIDeAUMsgEYD2lANhHCAFwXV0MDcpyIArgLblozXgOicyAZzBRQAc2ZSZIWZwC%20xYqEixEKAJKQ%20RLsAAmC6XLUawWFADFgEGqYAS9U9AA8e5BAAekCCmEsgGEHwAfMgAvMZkANoY2MigyADWEOiUMGh2eJgAuswkZGQIlHyYcFAQzAAUcMzJuPhJdoUANBTN%20W0thQCUsdEiglDiZTDANNoNAG5wNDx1edgF7dhdqSCYPGC96-0dwzHRVLT0IJNkshAHyPXAhsx6p9EtGwPIAD7cPDQaL9kDxghBpiAIKYbshbNhDhBJqo1AlMtlcp98IVOMQ4ShUHByHR3HBPFAfH5AhBgqFwlFYsgAEoQCpQUxeLiKOSdLiOZxuDzePSRYiRHF45COWZCylBEJhQzdVCy6nyglEiAksk%20SLROKlZAJPkuHYZLI5NDFNatTBJI1OFyFBIAcjxzsK2OI6g0mnA0HgSGQOHQdJVNIVEXiyAkzhZkHMLEuHC9GgqICksMJxMFUGaWc1Oa8wbpeqjMboCHjJS45Uq1VqDTg3XI72QAGo4MgALTt8g8srIabS3OPRbLCDdUB7MCtscrWIxOJT-b9sp3B71eZmCCUWfbygAOnLcahq7IeOYzoubBAztXqh5yNTlHTYEHMzmko-3mLithdgtMB8y1aBSwNAB6cDYVCCQAAtKABUxYVgqBKAAd2QBg-CgVCoGQWDoAnTDQglC0ACJj0rKEyOjeDEIoFAr1YK5nU5WMqITAAGHkuEgzCaAkShkBfGh0GQTBUMwUJyKAjUQKgGi4IQk1BH4mh0KhLgYGoZgAEYACYAGYU2IGBQUrYAX0wzBMFEqVtApAI5VpP9lSc1VQnVbNSSFXUnheMJulk7yyWaboh0-eyhSVSJhgNAB5cgACs4wPalLAgCR6gi6BBgPbSoAAUUQWD6nqVEsknXZ9iGEYo1rV9kDnFA4mCgsfKgCr0EKA9138iJBhxAdgFyTclnnABCOJeEBYY2vkrqepyqAxvHKrp0GrhVEGL0gA) (l. 44)

And if I set

```ts
function applyFilter<I extends Item, T extends TableHeader<I>>(item: I, tableHeader: T, filter: Filter<I, T>) {
  Object.entries(filter).forEach(([key, input]) => {
    const value = tableHeader[key].get(item);

    if (value != null) tableHeader[key].filter(value, input);
  })
}
```

I'm getting the error

```
Argument of type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2345)
```

(see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECydPIDeAUMsgEYD2lANhHCAFwXV0MDcpyIArgLblozXgOicyAZzBRQAc2ZSZIWZwC%20xYqEixEKAJKQ%20RLsAAmC6XLUawWFADFgEGqYAS9U9AA8e5BAAekCCmEsgGEHwAfMgAvMZkANoY2MigyADWEOiUMGh2eJgAuswkZGQIlHyYcFAQzAAUcMzJuPhJdoUANBTN%20W0thQCUsdEiglDiZTDANNoNAG5wNDx1edgF7dhdqSCYPGC96-0dwzHRVLT0IJNkshAHyPXAhsx6p9EtGwPIAD7cPDQaL9kDxghBpiAIKYbshbNhDhBJqo1AlMtlcp98IVOMQ4ShUHByHR3HBPFAfH5AhBgqFwlFYsgAEoQCpQUxeLiKOSdLiOZxuDzePSRYiRHF45COWZCylBEJhQzdVCy6nyglEiAksk%20SLROKlZAJPkuHYZLI5NDFNatTBJI1OFyFBIAcjxzsK2OI6g0mnA0HgSGQOHQdJVNIVEXiyAkzhZkHMLEuHC9GgqICksMJxMFUGaWc1Oa8wbpeqjMboCHjJS45Uq1VqDTg3XI72QAGo4MgALTt8g8srIabS3OPRbLCDdUB7MCtscrWIxOJT-b9sp3B71eZmCCUWfbygAOnLcahq7IeOYzoubBAztXqh5yNTlHTYEHMzmko-3mLithdgtMB8y1aBSwNAB6cDYVCCQAAtKABUxYVgqBKAAd2QBg-CgVCoGQWDoAnTDQglC0ACJj0rKEyOjeDEIoFAr1YK5nU5WMqITAAGHkuEgzCaAkShkBfGh0GQTBUMwUJyKAjUQKgGi4IQk1BH4mh0KhLgYGoZgAEYACYAGYU2IGBQUrYAX0wzBMFEqVtApAI5VpP9lSc1VQnVbNSSFXUnheMJulk7yyWaboh0-eyhSVSJhgNAB5cgACs4wPalLAgCR6gi6BBgPbSoAAUUQWD6nqVEsknXZ9iGEYo1rV9kDnFA4mCgsfKgCr0EKA9138iJBhxAdgFyTclnnABCOJeEBYY2vkrqepyqAxvHKrp0GrhVEGL0gA), l. 56) which is not totally surprising, question is, how can I resolve this error?

Comment: It is classic. Please see my [article](https://catchts.com/react-props) . `tableHeader[key].filter` producec a union of functions. This is usually not what you want. Usually you want an intersection of function. Please keep in mind that intersections of functions is in fact - function overloading. Please provide an example of how you want to call this function. Long story short - you need to change your approach

Comment: You will need quite a refactoring to convince the compiler this is safe, as essentially described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  It looks like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/w8Ye0N); does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you all. I would stick to @jcalz approach, it would be great if you could write up an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript cannot track correlations across [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types); if you've got a single code block like your `forEach()` callback body, the compiler can only analyze it once.  If you have multiple expressions in such a code block that depend on the same union-typed value, the compiler will usually just treat these expressions as being of union types themselves, but treat them independently. So a function that depends on a union key will become a union of functions.  And an argument that depends on a union key will become a union of arguments.  But you can't call a union of functions with a union of arguments safely; the compiler will [insist on an *intersection* of arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types).  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

The easiest approach here is to just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) liberally to quiet the errors because you're sure you're doing it right.

If you want the compiler to type check what you're doing, though, you can do a fairly large refactoring to use [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

This code has already gone through one round of such refactoring, but now you need to do it for the mapping type `T` from table header keys to the particular field type.  We have to keep `FieldHeader` generic in `K extends keyof TypeMap` to do it; it's fine for `FieldHeader<I>` to default to a union, but we want to be able to pick particular `K`:

```
type FieldHeader<I extends Item, K extends keyof TypeMap = keyof TypeMap> = {
  [P in K]: {
    compare: (a: TypeMap[P], b: TypeMap[P]) => number;
    filter: (value: TypeMap[P], input: TypeMap[P]) => boolean;
    get: (item: I) => TypeMap[P] | null | undefined;
    type: P;
  };
}[K];
```

And now your types need to be generic for that mapping `T`:

```
type TableHeader<I extends Item, T extends Record<keyof T, keyof TypeMap>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: FieldHeader<I, T[K]>
}

type Filter<I extends Item, T extends Record<keyof T, keyof TypeMap>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: TypeMap[T[K]];
}
```

And so you'll need to specify that when declaring variables of these types (you can use utility functions to infer instead of manually specifying, but I won't digress on that):

```
const tableHeader: TableHeader<MyItem, { selected: "boolean" }> = {
  selected: {
    compare: (a, b) => +a - +b,
    filter: (value, input) => value === input,
    get: (video) => video.selected,
    type: 'boolean',
  },
};

const filter: Filter<MyItem, { selected: "boolean" }> = {
  // ts should throw an error here, as type of "selected" should be 'boolean'
  selected: "",

  // also only props of "tableHeader" should be allowed
  foo: 123
}
```

And finally your `applyFilter()` function is also generic in `T` like this:

```
function applyFilter<I extends Item, T extends Record<keyof T, keyof TypeMap>>(
  item: I, tableHeader: TableHeader<I, T>, filter: Filter<I, T>
) {
  (Object.keys(filter) as Array<keyof T>).forEach(<K extends keyof T>(key: K) => {
    const input = filter[key];
    const value = tableHeader[key].get(item);
    if (value != null) tableHeader[key].filter(value, input);
  });
}
```

Note that we still need a type assertion for the compiler to see that `filter`'s entries has anything to do with `keyof T`, and in fact we can't use `Object.entries()` because that won't let us represent the relationship between `K` and `Filter<I, T>[K]` needed.  But otherwise it works; the compiler can see that `input` is of type `TypeMap[T[K]]`, and that `value` is of type `TypeMap[T[K]]` (after being checked for nullishness) and that `tableHeader[key].filter` is of type `(value: TypeMap[T[K]], input: TypeMap[T[K]]) => boolean`, so everything type checks.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-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-h5UAAKKIDRgxeHEyWOkGBWFMwMSLu0U5haW95gCRY01IUkZPoh11Xig+RlRW9LQHdaTNL+L4AoYixYsAmRvkc14AIT5Lw8LLO9FWfVA33oL9Y1g8ep7XLcQNcKoOOqEAA)